# Internal server when trying to load external asp.mvc website through code

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc, curl, wget

I'm trying to help out a colleague with a problem he is having. This means I don't have all debug information available, but thought maybe someone here could steer us in the right direction.

As stated in the title he is trying to load the html of an external website by code. He is in fact using cUrl. I have also tested using cUrl (php), file_get_contents (php), wget (terminal), and WebClient and HttpWebRequest (c#). The result is an internal server error message.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Innsyn.Controllers.BaseController.ExecuteCore() +673
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +61
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +53
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +468
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +374
```

As you can see the website he is trying to load is an asp.mvc application: http://einnsyn.harstad.kommune.no/einnsyn

When viewing the website with a browser the site works fine.

Comment: As you say, you might not have access to it, but it would be very useful to see `Innsyn.Controllers.BaseController.ExecuteCore()` to see what is causing the null reference exception.

Answer (score -1):

You need to supply http-headers. Use an browser plugin to look at the headers sent to the site when using a browser, then duplicate in your tool.
I used this method on eInnsyn to get data with wget.

Comment: When you answer a question, please provide precise indications and/or the rationale behind your advice if you give one. Your answer is overly general and is likely not going to help the original poster much. For example, you can elaborate on which headers might of interest, why you want to look at the headers, and so on.